# Bulk loading images

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, fetch

I have been trying to search how wallpaper apps bulk fetch images,for example do they mention a site name and fetch images from there and if they do so then how to get images sequentially because the url of a site remains same sohow they fetch images regularly in recycler view.Also I have read about using recycler view but most of the users say it is not smooth if we have 1000 images and continous use is going on?If you have an article on this or some code please suggest here.

Answer (score 0):

No I don't have any article but if you wanna learn more about loading images into recyclerview from server then you can follow this link [recyclerview tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-recyclerview-cardview-tutorial/)

By the way if you already know the use of `recyclerview` then you should cache `recyclerview`'s data

You can enable cache by following method :

```
    recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(30);
    //this is number of views you wanna cache you can change it as per your requirement
    recyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    recyclerView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
```

Comment: But still how so many images like ,developer wouldn't knowing about url of 1000 of image or even though he knows he won't be putting it manually